# Query SELECT DISTINCT count()

Tags: mysql, sql

Hello there I have the following doubt I want to count how many times in a month I enter data.
My database is:

- **Date:**
- 10/2010
- 10/2010
- 09/2010
- 08/2010

I have the following query.

```html
SELECT DISTINCT (date)
    FROM employee 
    WHERE date 
    IN (SELECT date 
    FROM employee 
GROUP BY date 
HAVING count( date ) >0) 
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

This query gives me:
Date:
10/2017
8/2017
9/2017

But I want you to give me something like that.

- Count | Date
- 2     |  10/2017
- 1     |   9/2017
- 1    |  10/2017

I hope I have explained my regards.

Comment: what data type is date? date or datetime, varchar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it; no subquery, or DISTINCT, needed.

```
SELECT `date`, count(*) 
FROM `employee`
GROUP BY `date`
HAVING count(*) > 0
ORDER BY `date` DESC;
```

I am a little confused as to what reason you would have for the `HAVING count() > 0` though; the only way something could have a zero count would mean it wasn't in the table (and therefore wouldn't show up anyway).

Other observations:

- DISTINCT is not a function; enclosing the `date` in parenthesis in the SELECT clause has absolutely no effect. (Also, DISTINCT is *almost* never appropriate for a GROUPing query.)
- `COUNT(somefield)` is the same as `COUNT(1)`, `COUNT(*)`. If you want the count of **unique** values you can do `COUNT(DISTINCT somefield)`; but it wouldn't make sense to `COUNT(DISTINCT groupingfield)` as that would always result in 1.

Answer (score 1):

The query you wrote is a bit complicated. Distinct and group by are doing the same thing for you here. When you do a group by count will automatically give you the count of grouped rows. Also you will have unique dates as well. Try this.

```
SELECT count(date), date
    FROM employee
GROUP BY date 
HAVING count( date ) >0
ORDER BY date DESC;
```

Comment: it would be really heapful to have a short description of what you are doing and what was the steps to come to your solution

Comment: Ya I felt that too. But the previous answer explained it pretty well. So I just left it. Will edit the same. Plus the above answer is the same steps I took. @MZaragoza

Comment: you should still write something, just in case the previews answer gets deletes and all there is left is yours